# Model doesn't accept its value

Tags: c#, mvvm, ms-access-2010

This code doesn't accept the values I give with the user's department data. If i replace user.Department.ID with just a simple int variable, it works fine. This is also the problem with user.Department.Code and user.Department.Title. I don't know what's the problem. Is it in my models?

This is the code. The system queries for the user data. I believe that the query is fine. I'm using a connection string with MS Access btw.

```
try
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                UserModel user = new UserModel();
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    user.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
                {
                    user.Department.Id = reader.GetInt32(1);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
                {
                    user.Department.Code = reader.GetString(2);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
                {
                    user.Department.Title = reader.GetString(3);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
                {
                    user.FamilyName = reader.GetString(4);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(5))
                {
                    user.GivenName = reader.GetString(5);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(6))
                {
                    user.MiddleName = reader.GetString(6);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
                {
                    user.NameSuffix = reader.GetString(7);
                }
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(8))
                {
                    user.Type = reader.GetString(8);
                }
                CurrentUser = user;
                CanLogin = true;   
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error");
        }
```

Here is my Usermodel...

```
class UserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FullName(bool isFamilyNameFirst)
        {
            StringBuilder fullname = new StringBuilder();
            if(isFamilyNameFirst)
            {
                fullname.Append(FamilyName).Append(", ").Append(GivenName).Append(" ").Append(MiddleName).Append(" ").Append(NameSuffix);
            }
            else
            {
                fullname.Append(GivenName).Append(" ").Append(MiddleName).Append(" ").Append(FamilyName).Append(" ").Append(NameSuffix);
            }
            return fullname.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And my Department Model..

```
class DepartmentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public InstitutionModel Institution { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: did you debug your code? userDepartment or reader has been initialized?

Comment: omg!! i found it!! i just set user.Department = new DepartmentModel() after the user declaration.. Peyman's answer is also correct so i'll set it as answered.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Department property never initialize any where, you an do it in user constructor:

```
class UserModel
{
    public UserModel()
    {
        this.Department = new DepartmentModel();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string NameSuffix { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FullName(bool isFamilyNameFirst)
    {
        StringBuilder fullname = new StringBuilder();
        if(isFamilyNameFirst)
        {
            fullname.Append(FamilyName).Append(", ").Append(GivenName).Append(" ").Append(MiddleName).Append(" ").Append(NameSuffix);
        }
        else
        {
            fullname.Append(GivenName).Append(" ").Append(MiddleName).Append(" ").Append(FamilyName).Append(" ").Append(NameSuffix);
        }
        return fullname.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or

```
UserModel user = new UserModel() {Department = new DepartmentModel()};
```

Comment: I'll use the first one because i'll be reusing the models a lot.. Thanks!! :D